# Why is sort with std::execution::par is taking longer than regular sort?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, stl, c++17, execution

Why does the identical vectors `v1` (normally) and `v2` (with **std::execution:parallel**) takes less time for `v1` and more time for `v2`?

I was expecting the parallel sort to complete faster.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <algorithm>
#include <execution>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    // Generate identical vectors v1 and v2 of length N
    // and fill them with v[i] = i/200;
    int N = 10000;
    vector<int> v1(N);
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++) v1[i] = i/200;
    auto v2 = v1;

    // Calculate the time taken to sort in serial way.
    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    sort(v1.begin(), v1.end());
    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto diff = end - start;
    cout << diff.count() << " = serial count" << endl;

    // Calculate the time taken to sort in parallel way using
    // std::execution::par
    start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    sort(std::execution::par, v2.begin(), v2.end());
    end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    diff = end - start;
    cout << diff.count() << " = parallel parallel" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Result:**

```
626600 = serial count
1048100 = parallel count
```

Comment: Change `int N = 10000;` to `long long N = 1000000000;` and see what happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int N = 10000;` is too small amount of elements for involving `std::execution::par`. Overheads for running and waiting for finishing threads can exceed serial run time with such a small amount of elements. In any case I get other results on onlinegdb.com (with -O2):

```
134692 = serial count
128443 = parallel count
```